What causes this bug in mvtnorm package in R?
I am conducting some nonlinear optimization using multivariate probabilities as my objective function. I've spent hours thinking I had issue with the optimization algorithm, but actually I've tracked the bug down to the use of the mvtnorm package.
Code
library(mvtnorm)
pmvnorm(
  lower = c(-1.281552 , 7.089083, 0.5193308),
  upper = c(-1.200552, Inf, Inf),
  corr = diag(1, nrow =3)
) 

If you excecute this code, every 10-20 times it will return NaN as opposed to 3.047822e-15.
Why is this the case? Can anyone enlighten me? Also, is there an alternative to mvtnorm::pmvnorm() that will prevent this type of instability?
Edit:

according to @LMc in comments you can reproduce the error using seed = 10L as an example
@PBull gives a great answer below in the comments
@Gregor Thomas in comments describes that using Miwa() fixes it (though Miwa I believe approximates -Inf/+Inf to -1e4/1e4

Session info

R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3.4.2
LAPACK: /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3.4.2
locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: system (glibc)
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
other attached packages:
[1] mvtnorm_1.2-4
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.1    tools_4.3.1       rstudioapi_0.16.0


With a slightly older version, mvtnorm version 1.2-3, I consistently get [1] 3.047822e-15 attr(,"error") [1] 0 attr(,"msg") [1] "Normal Completion".

Nevermind, ran it in a replicate with n = 1e4 and I am getting NaN a little over 5% of the time. But if I set algorithm = Miwa() it works consistently.

By default there is method dispatch to mvtnorm:::probval.GenzBretz() which then makes a C function called mvtnorm_C_mvtdst. This returns NaN. Other users can use seed = 10L as an example.

What happens is that the Monte Carlo lattice scrambling ends up with weights that cause this call to qnorm return Inf (the offending variable is W(ND) approaching 1). That isn't handled downstream and the return gets stuck at NaN after some more additions/multiplications. Note that you start integrating the standard normal at 7.09 which leaves almost no density to the right. FWIW this question shouldn't have been closed.

Thanks @PBulls that is fantastic detective work! I couldn't figure it out myself. I was considering multivariate rejection regions for graphical testing procedures, and optimization would search the whole parameter space (including the tails of the standard normal) - so I need a function that is robust to exploring tail densities.
Thanks so much for your insight (and I agree it shouldn't have been closed for the reason described).

@PBulls: please post your comment as an answer.

I can't claim to know much about the Genz-Bretz algorithm, but I recently ported mvt.f to C/SAS so I've been staring at its code for quite some time.
The result of this routine depends on pseudo-random number generation through Monte Carlo lattice scrambling -- whatever that means -- hence your issue only occurs for certain seeds. Very specifically this is the offending line:
Y(ND) = MVPHNV( DI + W(ND)*( EI - DI ) )

MVPHNV is actually a wrapper for R's qnorm inverse normal CDF function. Because you start the integration in one of your variates from a pretty extreme value the remaining density is already dangerously close to machine epsilon:
prt <- function(x, d=30) sprintf(paste0("%.", d, "f"), x)

p <- pnorm(7.089083)
#> 1

## Not *exactly* 1 however [see also pnorm(..., lower.tail = FALSE)]
prt(p)
#> "0.999999999999324984401027904823"

The Genz-Bretz algorithm perturbs these variates through W(ND), DI and EI above, which in some cases causes it to veer even closer to 1. Eventually the following happens:
qnorm(1)    ## Or within machine epsilon of 1
#> Inf

This isn't handled downstream, and a few additions/multiplications later the result becomes NaN from which it never recovers.
Now, this is indeed a bug in mvtnorm since it doesn't address this edge case correctly, but the underlying issue is that you're trying to do calculations for which the accuracy might be questionable to start with. The "true" answer is within an order of magnitude above machine epsilon, and it having an error of zero is most likely an underflow in the first place. You really can't go much further out into the tails either before you run into problems in general:
prt(pnorm(8.17))              ## Still not exactly 1
#> 0.999999999999999888977697537484

pnorm(8.17) == pnorm(8.29)    ## But 8.17 == 8.29?!
#> TRUE

prt(pnorm(8.30))
#> 1.000000000000000000000000000000

The calculation with lower.tail = FALSE is a little bit more accurate here but will be worse in the other direction. This is also the reason why mvtnorm::Miwa won't integrate out to infinity in your case; computers simply don't have infinite precision.

Brilliant answer thank you. Now I know how this is handled, I think I can handle the parameters upstream in my optimization by approximating Z statistics to 1e4, 1e-4 to avoid spending time searching the tails when I am exploring machine precision levels of difference. Many thanks!
